# Joomla migration to joomla 3.3.6

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.3

I have encountered a problem when updating my Joomla website to 3.3.6. Everything seems to be working fine but when I finished the update, my administrator panel and frontend are showing a blank white page.

I have tried renaming the component file to component_delete in a legacy folder using ftp as suggested by cloudaccess website but still there is till a blank page

Comment: hey @Lodder, i hav  rename the component folder to component_delete as suggested by[link](http://www.cloudaccess.net%2Fabout-us%2Fblog%2Fentry%2F2013%2F11%2F13%2Fupgrading-from-joomla-3-1-to-3-2-problems-workarounds.html&ei=HBa9VIaMCsHTaN_rgfAK&usg=AFQjCNFdN6weJon7s6Vq4zuYKoYReJkNNA&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d2s)

Comment: and it didnt work..then i got another solution of renaming the remember.php file to remember-bak.php and then renaming it back after i got access to my backend[link](http:www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsHenu3JmKg) and then the website was fine let me know of your opinion for this solutions...otherwise i think anyone with a white blank page after updating your joomla website should try them

Comment: Forget about renaming stuff. The reason why you're getting a blank screen is because there are PHP errors but they are turned off/disabled. So you need to turn them on

Comment: how do you turn them on@lodder

Comment: In your *configuration.php*, go to line **23** and make sure `$error_reporting` it set to `development`

Comment: Do as @Lodder suggest you. This will displays the error why you are seeing a blank page, this is probably because of a fatal error. also set the $debug to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cpanel, go to phpmyadmin and in the joomla database look for a table called extensions.

Then look for the plugin 'remember' and disable it by changing its value from 1 to 0.

Then go back to your joomla installation and refresh the page. Remember to fix your database structure after the update and also purge the cache. I recommend using a component called AdminTools